how to handle letters as NaN in a column of floats?
In Python I have a column of numbers and strings that I read in with Pandas from an Excel table. Object type is string for the whole column after read from excel. As I only need the rows which contain numbers for further processing I would like to dismiss the rows containing letters.
How can I handle handle letters as NAN?
After reading in I have the following column in string format:
print(df)
0          sometext
1             0.510
2             3.565
3             2.695
4             0.899
5             1.361
6          sometext
7             4.587
8             1.745
9             10.020
Name: info, dtype: object

and
print(type(df['info']))

gives
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

the cells contain all strings:
print(type('info'[1]))
<class 'str'>

My aim is
print(df)
0             0.510
1             3.565
2             2.695
3             0.899
4             1.361
5             4.587
6             1.745
7             10.020

or -alternatively-
print(df)
0               NAN
1             0.510
2             3.565
3             2.695
4             0.899
5             1.361
6               NAN
7             4.587
8             1.745
9             10.020

What do I have to add to df = np.float64(df['info']) that it can handle the letters as nan values if it is not possible to convert the cells into floats?

Use pd.to_numeric(df['info'], errors='coerce')
